# Controller name for Http Routing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

Can I somehow get the controller name in the routing mapping the WebApiConfig?

What I'd like to do is match a part of the controller name to an action.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ApiGetAllDefault",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = "Get" + controllerName + "s" },
    constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) }
);
```

**Update**: The reason for all this is when I do the routing as

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ApiById",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { id = @"^[0-9]+$" }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ApiByActionId",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: null,
    constraints: new { id = @"^[0-9]+$" }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ApiByAction",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: null
);

/* Default route */
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

requests like `api/World/GetWorld/5` with the action name included do match but some other requests like `api/World/5` don't or respectively would match to more than one action. Since I didn't find a proper default mapping between route and action, I had the idea to define more specific routes for all of my controllers.

```
foreach (Type t in GetTypesInNamespace(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), "MyProject.Controllers")) {
    if (typeof(ApiController).IsAssignableFrom(t)) { // Make sure that this controller class is deriving from api controller
        string controllerName = t.Name.Substring(0, t.Name.LastIndexOf("Controller"));  // Remove Controller postfix from name
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiGet" + controllerName,
            routeTemplate: "api/" + controllerName + "/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = controllerName, action = "Get" + controllerName },
            constraints: new { id = @"^[0-9]+$", httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiGet" + controllerName + "s",
            routeTemplate: "api/" + controllerName + "/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = controllerName, id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = "Get" + controllerName + "s" },
            constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) }
        );
    }
}
```

This solution is working for me, but I'd still like to know if there's a generic route in order to match reuqest without the action name to default actions.

Comment: Please explain a bit more of desired outcome. I'm not clear what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this defining controller + action in WebApiConfig

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ActionApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

OR

You can check this

```
routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithId", "Api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }, new { id = @"\d+" });
routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithAction", "Api/{controller}/{action}");
routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiGet", "Api/{controller}", new { action = "Get" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) });
routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiPost", "Api/{controller}", new {action = "Post"}, new {httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Post)});
```

For More Information Visit [Routing in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: Response from Fiddler:
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:52498/api/World'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'World' that matches the name 'Get'."}

Here's the action signature from the controller:
// GET api/World
        public Object GetWorlds()

Comment: Did you change the webapi name check this http://forums.asp.net/t/1916587.aspx?WebAPI+No+HTTP+resource+was+found+that+matches+the+request+URI

Answer (score 2):

If you to restrict one controller so you do like following.

```
  routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                  constraints: new {controller = "FrontEnd" }
            );
```

`constraints` allow only FrontEnd controller